# JSColor pick up color to trigger AngularJS ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jscolor

I use this plugin, JSColor (http://jscolor.com/)
and bind the input value with AngularJS ng-model like the following:

```
<input class="color" ng-model="myColor" ng-change="alert(myColor)">
```

I expect everytime I pick up a color AngularJS will alert the changed value of myColor, but nothing happens.

What else should I do? thank you! :)

---

add:

I also tried this:

```
<input class="color" ng-model="myColor"> 
<textarea style="color:#{{myColor}}>texttext</textarea>
```

to bind text color in textarea, also doesn't works.

Comment: you need somehow call [`$scope.$apply()`](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) when your changes are outside of AngularJS, you can get the `$scope` by either implementing [own custom directive](http://www.smartjava.org/content/drag-and-drop-angularjs-using-jquery-ui) or [from the dom element](http://makandracards.com/makandra/15851-angularjs-access-the-scope-for-a-rendered-dom-element).

Answer (score 0):

Angular [expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) (as in ng-change) are evaluated against the scope, so window's objects are not visible. If you want to call alert on change you can create a function on the scope that does it:

```
$scope.alert = function(myColor) {
    alert(myColor);
}
```

Or with injecting the $window service:

```
.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.alert = function(color) {
        $window.alert(color);
    }
})
```

Comment: it still doesn't work :( and my main point is ng-change doesn't work in this case.

Comment: I also tried this:

<input class="color" ng-model="myColor">
<textarea style="color:#{{myColor}}>texttext</textarea>

to bind text color in textarea, also doesn't works.

Comment: you need to add to your question your javascript code

Answer (score 0):

Your on-change is not fired because of the alert called.
 **ng-change="alert(myColor)"**

```
   $scope.alert = function(myColor) {
   alert(myColor);
}
```