# Angular: how can I use JavaScript referenced in index.html in a component template?

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular newbie here.

I have a color picker (jscolor) which works perfectly in my index.html, but I can't seem to use it the same way via my component template.

I have a script tag reference to it in the head of index.html.  If I use the  tag in index.html, it works perfectly.  However, if I use  in a component template, it doesn't work at all.  I thought after transpilation, the template code would read as part of index.html.

How can I use the jscolor associated html tag in my component template?

JSColor documentation [here](http://jscolor.com/)

Comment: You'll probably have to dive into their code a bit. My guess is that the code is looking for and registering elements as soon as it runs and therefore doesn't see elements that are added later. See if they have public methods to call to re-register or re-initialize the control.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly inject the library to the code and execute it once your application is loaded.

Not sure which angular version you are using, but those threads might help you:

*AngularJS* [JSColor pick up color to trigger AngularJS ng-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600230/jscolor-pick-up-color-to-trigger-angularjs-ng-change)

*Angular*
[Importing jscolor library in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391075/importing-jscolor-library-in-angular-2)